# C++ Controlling destructor order for global objects

Tags: c++, memory-management, global-variables, destructor

I've got a class (A) that accesses (indirectly via a static method) a static variable (an STL container) in another class (B) in its constructor and destructor.

A objects may be global, global constants, static members of another class, stored in other classes (which may themselves have global or static instances) or basically anywhere else a c++ object can be.

If an A object is constructed before the static members in B or destructed after the static members in B, it will cause a crash at some point (usually an access violation).

Is there some way to guarantee that all instances of class A (except those that have leaked, since by definition there "lost" and so wont be destructed any way) are constructed after and destructed before B's static variable?

I've seen some solutions for making a specific variable be constructed/destructed before/after another, however not a general case of all instances of a given type so am not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. This is known as the [static-initialization fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15). The order that objects get constructed prior to entering main is unspecified. The only guarantee is that it happens.

What you can do is lazy-initialize. This means your objects won't be initialized until you use them. Such as:

```
struct A { /* some data */ };
struct B { B(void){ /* get A's data */ } };

A& get_A(void)
{
    static A instance;
    return instance;
}

B& get_B(void)
{
    static B instance;
    return instance;
}
```

You use `get_A` and `get_B` to get the global instances. The part where `B` uses `A` should use `get_A`, and your use of `B` should be with `get_B`. Note the `get_B` is optional in your case.

What happens when B is first created? (Either globally or in the function) The constructor will call `get_A` and *that's* where `A` will be created. This let's you control the order things get constructed.

Note I think I reversed your A and B.

Comment: He's asking about destruction, not initialisation.

Comment: @Neil: Destruction order is determined by initialization order, though.

Comment: So I can just change my "static Container container" to "static Container& getContainer(){static Container container;return container;}" and it would deallocated after anything that directly or indirectly called getContainer in it's constructor? What if an instance of A was stored into a global shared_ptr at some point later in the program?

Comment: You're still opening yourself up for trouble, as the previous C++ FAQ entry (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14) mentions regarding static objects vs. static pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no such method. There are workarounds, though. You can get an object with global scope and a slightly-less-than global lifetime by having a global pointer and initializing/destructing it in main/WinMain. Also, you place your global state to be destructed last in a ref-counted heap object.

Also, consider redesign :)

Answer (score 1):

The book ["Modern C++ Design"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Modern-Design-Applied-Generic-Patterns/dp/0201704315) covers this issue nicely.

Google Books contains scans of much of it - see section 6.5 (page 135) - [link](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aJ1av7UFBPwC&lpg=PP1&dq=modern%20c%2B%2B%20design&pg=PA135#v=onepage&q=&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this cleanly, by putting pointers to the objects in global space,
then newing them in the desired order in your main, and destroying them in the desired order at the end of the main.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed, there is no standard and portable way to solve this problem, due to the  [Static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15) issue.

However, you should be able to solve your problem by applying a bit of design, so you gain a degree of control when (and how) objects of A and B are constructed. Take a look on design patterns like creational pattern [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) it is considered in many (if not most) cases as [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern), despite it is worth to learn about it. Also look at to [Monostate](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=147) pattern which may be used as a bit better Singleton. These patterns can help to control object creation and lifetime, so things are properly initialized before use.

Generally, it's a good idea to avoid globals - sticking to [deglobalisation](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1470) is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you use lazy singletons (that return on-demand created statics) you may end up with possibility where one singleton uses another one after it was already deleted. For example, imagine you have a global `HttpClient` singleton that allows you to make http requests. Also, you probably want to have logging, which might be provided by `Log` singleton:

```
class HttpClient
{
    ...
    static HttpClient& singleton()
    {
        static HttpClient http;
        return http;
    }
};
```

Same for `Log` singleton. Now, imagine `HttpClient` constructor and destructor simply log that that `HttpClient` was created and deleted. In this case destructor of `HttpClient` may end up using deleted `Log` singleton.

[Sample code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0048e3bfbdce8c8c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Log
{
    Log()
    {
        msg("Log");
    }

    ~Log()
    {
        msg("~Log");
    }

public:    
    static Log& singleton()
    {
        static Log log;
        return log;
    }

    void msg(const char* str)
    {
        puts(str);
    }
};

class HttpClient
{
    HttpClient()
    {
        Log::singleton().msg("HttpClient");
    }
    ~HttpClient()
    {
        Log::singleton().msg("~HttpClient");
    }

public:
    static HttpClient& singleton()
    {
        static HttpClient http;
        return http;
    }
    void request()
    {
        Log::singleton().msg("HttpClient::request");
    }
};

int main()
{
    HttpClient::singleton().request();
}
```

and the output is:

```
 Log
 HttpClient
 HttpClient::request
 ~HttpClient
 ~Log
```

So far everything is correct, simply because it happened that `Log` was constructed before `HttpClient`, which means that `HttpClient` can still use `Log` in its destructor. Now simply comment out logging code in `HttpClient` constructor and you'll end up with [this output](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/feb45cad6fdb3822):

```
Log
HttpClient::request
~Log
~HttpClient
```

As you can see, log is being used after its destructor `~Log` was already called. As pointed out, deglobalization might be a better approach, but if you want to use on-demand created singletons and make some of them live longer than the others, then you can make such singletons [use a global static initialized on demand](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77e3f033f1de9a2b). I use that approach quite often in production code:

```
class Log
{
    friend std::unique_ptr<Log>::deleter_type;
    ...
    static std::unique_ptr<Log> log;

    static Log& createSingleton()
    {
        assert(!log);
        log.reset(new Log);
        return *log;
    }

public:    
    static Log& singleton()
    {
        static Log& log = createSingleton();
        return log;
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<Log> Log::log;
```

Now, regardless of order in which these singletons were constructed, destruction order will ensure that `Log` is destructed after `HttpClient`. This, however, might still fail and produce unexpected output if `HttpClient` was used from a global static constructor. Or if you want to have multiple such "super" globals (like `Log` and `Config` for example) that use each other in random order, you will still have these problem. In such cases sometimes it's just better allocate once on heap never delete some of these objects.

Comment: (just a note, I'm aware the question is almost a decade old, just wanted to post sample code in case if somebody comes across)